# php input data passing without submit but reloading the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I created a site that the form and the table of the database are in the same page.  When I fill the form and click on the submit button, record will be added to the table and show it correctly.  But when I refresh the page, the form will remember the data that I typed last and submit them to the table without clicking submit button.  I want to pass data to the table only by clicking the submit button.  How can I stop passing data by refreshing the page?

This is my form:

```
form action = "#" method="POST" >

//some inputs

input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>

/form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't submit to the same page. Submit to different page, and redirect back to the first page with:

```
header('Location: firstpage.php');
exit;
```

after storing the data in the page that processes the form.